# forcing new line in a text box thats populated programmatically (Lucee cfml)

Tags: html, cfml, lucee

How can i add a new line character in a text input box that's being populated by a Lucee script?
The idea is this: I have a script that's querying a database and popuating the text box with what it thinks i need in the text box.  I will then check the contents of the textbox using my MK1 eyeballs and modify it as needed.   Currently the text teh script is producing is all in one line like this:
`CohostID|int|\ Name|nvarchar|\ email|nvarchar|\ datecreated|datetime|\ dateupdated|datetime|\ isVisible|bit|((1))\ timezone|nvarchar|\`  in a single line.
But what i want to do is have a new line character at the end of each element so it looks more like this:

CohostID|int|
Name|nvarchar|
email|nvarchar|
datecreated|datetime|
dateupdated|datetime|
isVisible|bit|((1))
timezone|nvarchar|\

I've tried every method i know to put a new line character into my script in such a way that it doesnt appear as characters in the text box.  I've tried adding '\n' after the |\characters, and the  html '
' but they dont work here.  But I'm afraid i'm stumped.

I just KNOW this is going to be one of those "slap the forehead" moments but it just won't come to front of mind.
Cheers
Mike Kear
Windsor, NSW, Australia